# Loading DLL generated by MATLAB Coder with function, that calls outer functions

Tags: c++, matlab, dll, matlab-coder

I have a DLL file, generated by MATLAB Coder, that contains function `Adjust`. This functions calls for few outer functions written in outer .m files, e.g `PulseFindAdapt`:

```
function [Indexes,NoiseLogBinary,NoiseThreshold]=Adjust(NoiseLog,NoiseTime,MedianLong)%значения аргументов

NoiseLog = NoiseLog/8192;
NoiseLog=NoiseLog-my_medFilt(NoiseLog,MedianLong);
mean = 45;

[Indexes,NoiseLogBinary,NoiseThreshold]=PulseFindAdapt(NoiseLog,NoiseTime,mean,7);
end
```

When I try to load generated Adjust.dll file using `QLibrary`, I get following error:

```
"Cannot load library Adjust.dll: the specified module could not be found"
```

Here I found a suggestion, that the problem could be to load one of .dll dependencies(last post):

[Problem with dependencies](https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/29209-Library-(-dll)-found-but-not-loading-when-running-outside-Qt-Creator)

I tried loading other .dll files,containing only one function without and dependencies, and it worked, so the problem isn't in using `QLibrary`; also tried including headers and linking .cpp files with generated code for functions(e.g `PulseFindAdapt`), but it didn't work. Any suggestions how to load and use such .dll?

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried using DependencyWalker http://www.dependencywalker.com/ to take a look at the dependencies of Adjust.dll ?

Comment: Thanks fow answer! Yes, it really was dependecy issue. I was lack of `libiomp5md.dll`. Also, my colleague advised me to use static linking instead of dynamic, and that helped me to fix linking errors before executing application.

Comment: If it helped you i posted an answer dont't hesitate to upvote ans accept. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For all problem concerning linking error dont' hesitate to use DependencyWalker www.dependencywalker.com .

It wiil give dependency and functions